# Rails Database Query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to gather information from a database and then pass that information on to my view via flash. Unfortunately the information is formatting in an ActiveRecord::Relation and not in any format that I can read.

Controller Query

```
@message = Message.where(:all).limit(4).order(id: :desc).only(:order,:where)    
    flash[:response] = @message
    redirect_to (:back)
```

If I do something like

```
@message = Message.where(:all).limit(4).order(id: :desc).only(:order,:where)    
    flash[:response] = @message.first.mess
    redirect_to (:back)
```

To try and get the first returned value in the mess column, I get an undefined method error. I have been trying to find a tutorial that tells me how to take information once my query has been run but I have not had much luck with Rail's tutorials as of late. I appreciate any help that you guys can give. After I do this I am going to try to format the 4 different results on the view side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List of messages:

```
@messages = Message.order(id: :desc).limit(4)
```

This: `only(:order,:where)` cancels your `limit(4)` (why?)

`@messages` is now an activerecord association, not suitable to output.... So, if you have 4 messages top you can do:

```
if @messages.any? # maybe no messages come out
    flash[:response] = @messages.map(&:mess).join('<br>') # add an html newline between them
end
redirect_to :back
```

Comment: So I understand the query as such - SELECT * FROM Messages ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT 4. However my query is not returning anything (I get the error 'undefined method 'any?' for nil:NilClass') I feel as though I understand the code but then I don't understand why I am not getting any result from the query as the syntax seems fine to me.

Comment: Sorry submitted by hitting enter by accident

Comment: Do you have a Message class?

Comment: Yes a simple one - class Message < ActiveRecord::Base validates :mess, :presence => true validates :user, :presence => true end

Comment: Run this in console: `Message.order(id: :desc).limit(4)`, what do you get?

Comment: I get a proper result. #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Message id:4, mess: "Hello", user: "Bob", created_at... etc. All 4 results are shown.

Comment: Then I can only assume you are mistyping something... Did you notice `@messages` instead of `@message`?

Comment: No I didn't. Sorry about that. It works now and I thank you very much for your help. I was able to get a list of all the messages on the view side. Thank you so much.

Comment: Maybe you could cast a vote then or pick my answer :)